# Implementing dynamic strings in golang

Tags: string, go

I have following global string,

```
studentName := "Hi ? ,Welcome"
```

Now I want to take this string dynamically

```
func returnName(name string) string{
    return studentName+name
}
```

This function should return string as

```
Hi name,welcome.
```

string should take name from parameter,and return dynamic string.What is the best way to implement this in golang.

Comment: I think `fmt.Sprintf` is the best way to go if you don't have any complex template processing to do.

Comment: yes,thanx for notifying :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to keep things simple, you can probably just use `fmt.Sprintf`.

```
studentName := fmt.Sprintf("Hi, %s! Welcome.", name)
```

The `%s` part will get replaced by the value of `name`.

Comment: This is the simplest most obvious solution, unless a complex template is needed, there really isn't a reason not to choose this one, OP

Answer (score 8):

If your input gets bigger (more complex) or if you need to substitute different values multiple times, then templates are more effective, cleaner and more flexible. Check out the [`text/template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package.

The `template` package parses your template once, builts a tree from it, and once you need to replace values, it builds the output on the fly.

Take a look at this example:

```
const templ = `Hi {{.Name}}!
Welcome {{.Place}}.
Please bring {{.ToBring}}
`
```

You can parse such a template with this line:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
```

Prepare its input data either as a `struct` or as a `map`:

```
data := map[string]string{
    "Name":    "Bob",
    "Place":   "Home",
    "ToBring": "some beers",
}
```

And you can have the result with [`Template.Execute()`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute):

```
err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data) // Prints result to the standard output
```

**Here's the complete, runnable example:** (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IiE_8sA4taB))

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    data := map[string]string{
        "Name":    "Bob",
        "Place":   "Home",
        "ToBring": "some beers",
    }
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil { // Prints result to the standard output
        panic(err)
    }

    // Now change something:
    data["Name"] = "Alice"
    data["ToBring"] = "a Teddy Bear"
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ = `
Hi {{.Name}}!
Welcome {{.Place}}.
Please bring {{.ToBring}}
`
```

**Output:**

```
Hi Bob!
Welcome Home.
Please bring some beers

Hi Alice!
Welcome Home.
Please bring a Teddy Bear
```

**Getting the result as a `string`:**

If you want the result as a `string`, you can write the result to a [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) and get the `string` using the `Buffer.String()` method:

```
buf := bytes.Buffer{}
t.Execute(&buf, data)
var result string = buf.String()
```

Complete program (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/4UUycgSUjIY)):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    data := map[string]string{
        "Name":    "Bob",
        "Place":   "Home",
        "ToBring": "some beers",
    }
    fmt.Print(Execute(data))
}

var t = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))

func Execute(data interface{}) string {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    if err := t.Execute(&buf, data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    return buf.String()
}

const templ = `
Hi {{.Name}}!
Welcome {{.Place}}.
Please bring {{.ToBring}}
`
```

Answer (score 3):

You could consider the function [strings.Replace](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace)

```
return Replace(studentName, "? ", name, 1)
```

With '1', it replaces the first "? " it finds in `studentName`.
Replace returns a copy of `studentName`, with `"? "` substituted with `name`.

This *strictly* respect the original question (global var with that exact content)

---

Now, if you start changing the question, like for instance with a different content (a global variable `studentName := "Hi %s ,Welcome"`), *then* you could use [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) as in [425nesp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419891/425nesp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29072087/6309)

```
return fmt.Sprintf(studentName, name)
```

That would use the format 'verbs' `%s`, default format for string.

Comment: thanx,this is the simplest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the global string is always the same you could do.

```
func returnName(name string) string {
   buf := bytes.Buffer{}
   buf.WriteString("Hi ")
   buf.WriteString(name)
   buf.WriteString(", welcome")
   return buf.String()
}
```

or

```
func returnName(name string) string {
   return "Hi " + name + ", welcome"
}
```

if the string is a dynamic template you could use the template package or a simple Replace if there wont be other `?` marks or Sprintf

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [template.Template](//pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template)
combined with `strings.Builder`:

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "text/template"
)

func returnName(name string) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse("Hi {{.}}, welcome.")).Execute(b, name)
   return b.String()
}

func main() {
   println(returnName("Akash"))
}
```